# Getting exception while instantiating KafkaProducer

Tags: apache-kafka, ibm-cloud, websphere-liberty, message-hub

I am using IBM Bluemix implementation of the Kafka Broker.

I am creating the KafkaProducer with following properties:

```
key.serializer=org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.ByteArraySerializer
value.serializer=org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.ByteArraySerializer
bootstrap.servers=xxxx.xxxxxx.xxxxxx.xxxxxx.bluemix.net:xxxx
client.id=messagehub
acks=-1
security.protocol=SASL_SSL
ssl.protocol=TLSv1.2
ssl.enabled.protocols=TLSv1.2
ssl.truststore.location=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
ssl.truststore.password=xxxxxxxx
ssl.truststore.type=JKS
ssl.endpoint.identification.algorithm=HTTPS

KafkaProducer<byte[], byte[]> kafkaProducer = 
           new KafkaProducer<byte[], byte[]>(props);
```

With this I got following exception:

> org.apache.kafka.common.KafkaException:
>   org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.internals.DefaultPartitioner is not
>   an instance of org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.Partitioner

After reading the following blog:
http://blog.rocana.com/kafkas-defaultpartitioner-and-byte-arrays I added the following line to my property file, even though I was using new API:

```
partitioner.class=kafka.producer.ByteArrayPartitioner
```

Now I am getting this exception:

> org.apache.kafka.common.KafkaException: Could not instantiate class
>   kafka.producer.ByteArrayPartitioner Does it have a public no-argument
>   constructor?

It looks like `ByteArrayPartitioner` does not have a default constructor.
Any idea what I am missing here?

Thanks
Madhu

Answer (score 0):

As I was using the KafkaProducer API, I did not need

```
partitioner.class=kafka.producer.ByteArrayPartitioner
```

property. The issue was there were 2 copies of the kafkaclient jar. We have configured our installation such that all library jar files are in an external shared directory. But due to the POM configuration error the war file also had a copy of the kafka client in its lib directory. Once I fixed this issue, it worked fine.

Madhu